# No clock signal when using SPIDRV on EFM32GG STK3700 devboard?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, gpio, spi

I'm using the EFM32GG STK3700 board, and have an oscilloscope hooked up to the exp pins GND and PD2. The MCU pin PD2 is mapped to peripheral pin USART1_CLK, and as seen in the code below, I am initializing SPI with using USART1. I have verified that all the code runs, even the success part of the TransferComplete call-back function. The problem is that even if I continually run transfers in the main-loop as below, the clock signal shows nothing but a flat line on the oscilloscope, and chip select is always high.

```
#include "spidrv.h"
#include "em_usart.h"

SPIDRV_HandleData_t handleData;
SPIDRV_Handle_t handle = &handleData;

void TransferComplete( SPIDRV_Handle_t handle,
                       Ecode_t transferStatus,
                       int itemsTransferred )
{
  if ( transferStatus == ECODE_EMDRV_SPIDRV_OK )
  {
    // Success !
  }
}

uint8_t buffer[8];

void app_init(void)
{
  SPIDRV_Init_t initData = SPIDRV_MASTER_USART1;

  // Init
  SPIDRV_Init( handle, &initData );

}

void app_process_action(void)
{
  SPIDRV_MTransmitB( handle, buffer, 10 );

  SPIDRV_MTransmit( handle, buffer, 10, TransferComplete );
}
```